# What is the proper way of creating web gallery?

Tags: php, javascript, html, web, gallery

I am new in web development but I have worked with html and php as far as web development but I haven't built an entire website for commercial use. I only worked with html and php while I was in school for projects.

By the way I am in grad school, with not much experience.

Here is the thing, I want to create a web page to represent my photographs and designs and I faced the following problem:
I want to have a single html page with either a link as text or a button to navigate to the next and another button for previous picture.

When it came to the point of changing the picture, I created a javascript to switch to a particular picture but this is not quite what I want, I would like it to be dynamic, meaning, is there any way to write code that read all the name of pictures in the server where my website will reside and then put them in an array or something then loop through them forward and backward.

I know that javascript is for the user side and php is for the server side, also I know it's not a good idea to let javascript access directory the way I described.

So I just need some help or ideas to accomplish this task the proper way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: why don't you let php provide an array of image paths for javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your goal?  Is it to learn web development or to create a website that you can show off some pictures on?

If it's the latter, then I would recommend just setting up a [wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) site and installing a photo gallery plugin.

If you want to do everything yourself, then I would use some javascript library like [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) (there are many more that are similar) on your current site.  Store the image info in a mySql database, pull the image paths through to the site using PHP, and then use the js library of your choice so you aren't re-inventing the wheel when it comes to the actual functionality of the gallery.

Comment: Actually it's kind of booth, I would like to learn and create my own website.
I know about wordpress because my bother who is not a programer, is using it and he likes it but he does not have much control.

Ok, so it seems that I need both php and javascript which is fine but is there a book or something that explain who to do all this puzzle, I mean using php and pass information to a different programming language. Also how do I install MySQL in my web host.
I am sorry if the last question seems naive to others but I came from local machine type of programmer.

Comment: It's really outside of the scope of what can be answered on a forum like this.  After all, people make entire careers out of building websites.  I would recommend checking out your local library or book store for some material on PHP and mySql.  Of course, sites like this are a great resource, although this question might be too vague.  See if your web host offers support or can help with the mySql installation.  If you run into issues with it, post a more specific question here.

Comment: There are also online tutorial sites, such as http://www.lynda.com/PHP-tutorials/php-with-mysql-essential-training/435-2.html - That particular site costs money, but there may be some free ones out there.  Good luck.

Comment: I really appreciate your guidance, my problem is that my questions most of the time seems vague and ambiguous even though you answered my original question, don't worry about the one in the comment.
I am not trying to make living building websites, it's just I like to learn how things work and do them myself.
To me it's a shame to be a computer scientist and not able to understand how some stuff works like my first question that's why I wanted to learn the PROPER way not the sneaky way or the hacking way, after all I want to do things professionally.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MySQL database to store information about each image, including the filename.

The on the frontend, query the database for the filename and use your standard HTML  to build a src using the filename stored in the database.  Meaning the file itself it stored in a directory somewhere.

Do it this way allows you to build a really robust system down the road because you'll be able to query the database for as much, as little, or as specific information you want.  From this database query, you can then return all the filenames that match the query and then loop through them to display in your javascript frontend.